# How to use Python decorators to optimize writing different methods which do similar job?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am a beginner in Python and I need some help on decorators. I am writing a few methods which call other methods that are generated using swagger. Basically all these swagger methods have GET APIs. All I need to do in my code is to call those swagger methods and return the value. I am looking for ways to optimize this instead of writing the same kind of method for each API. I came across decorators which can be used in this case. But my implementation is not giving the desired result

```
def get_component_info(self, func):
    def inner():
        data = None
        try:
            ret = func()
            if ret.status == 200:
                log.info('ret ' + str(ret))
            else:
                logging.error('Error: ' + str(ret.text))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(" failed with error " + str(e.reason) +
                            " and error code " + str(e.status))
        finally:
            return data
    return inner()

def get_firewall_info(self):
    return self._monitor.list_firewall_monitors_with_http_info()     <-- swagger method

def get_firewall_info_caller(self):
    get_firewall_info = self.get_component_info(self.get_firewall_info())
```

But the above implementation always return None because it never executes `self._monitor.list_firewall_monitors_with_http_info()`, but the test isn't failing

If you help me fix this, then I can use the same for getting server info, auth info, network info, etc. If decorators can't be used, what else I can use to optimize this..?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the decorator? You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: get_component_info() is the decorator. I have given the example in the description. Are you looking for anything specific..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are usually functions which take a second function as an argument and then define and return a third function which calls the second function while changing its input and/or output. It looks like you have a better handle on this than I did as a beginner.

```py
def decorator(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do stuff here...
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # ...or here.
        return value
    return inner
```

The only change I would recommend to your decorator is not to call `inner` and return the result, but to return the function itself. When you make this change you'll have to call the function you are returning now after it is returned.

```py
    def get_component_info(self, func):
        def inner():
            # ...
        return inner

    def get_firewall_info_caller(self):
        # You will now want to call the `inner` function after you get
        # it from `get_component_info`.
        get_firewall_info = self.get_component_info(...)()
```

It looks like the core of your bug is that you aren't providing a function to `get_component_info`; you're providing the result of calling that function. I think that changing the code to not call `get_firewall_info` should fix your code.

```py
    def get_firewall_info_caller(self):
        # You don't want to call the function you're providing to a
        # decorator, since it's expecting the function not the result.
        get_firewall_info = self.get_component_info(self.get_firewall_info)()
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it as shown below. Not sure if it is the right approach. Please correct me

```
def get_component_info(self, func):
    def inner():
        data = None
        try:
            ret = func()
            if ret.status == 200:
                log.info('ret ' + str(ret))
            else:
                logging.error('Error: ' + str(ret.text))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(" failed with error " + str(e.reason) +
                            " and error code " + str(e.status))
        finally:
            return data
    return inner

def get_firewall_info(self):
    data = self.get_component_info(self._monitor.list_firewall_monitors_with_http_info)()
    return data
```